# Write a Struts2 Plugin

Tags: plugins, struts2

Can anybody suggest me some tutorial or documentation to write Struts2 Plugin other than the official one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found this tutorial useful - [Write a Struts2 Plugin](http://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/struts2/writing-a-struts-2-plugin.html)